# How does this js know $get is function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

Tags: javascript

So I've been looking at a [blog post](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/restoring-lost-focus-in-update-panel.html) with some javascript in it and there is something I'm looking at which I don't quite follow:

```
function pageLoadedHandler(sender, args) {  
    if (typeof(lastFocusedControlId) !== "undefined" 
         && lastFocusedControlId != "")   
    {  
        var newFocused = $get(lastFocusedControlId);  
        if (newFocused) {    
            focusControl(newFocused);
        }
    }
```

In the above method it calls **$get** which i assume is an alias to

```
 function(id) { 
     return document.getElementById(id); 
 }
```

There is nowhere in the supplied js file where $get is declared.

Is this a reserved alias and can someone provide the link which provies it. If not how does it know what $get is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I've found them:
Quoting Msdn

**Sys.UI.DomElement $get Method**

> Provides a shortcut to the getElementById method of the Sys.UI.DomElement class. This member is static and can be invoked without creating an instance of the class.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Global/GetShortCutMethod.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397717.aspx

Very difficult to search for $get

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking at ASP.NET's AJAX shortcuts.

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/the_everuseful_get_and_find_as.html

Answer (score 1):

The example you mention is based on ASP .NET, [$find](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Global/FindShortCutMethod.aspx) and [$get](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Global/GetShortCutMethod.aspx) are two ["shortcut" functions](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/the_everuseful_get_and_find_as.html) provided by the MS Ajax Framework